# form file input (image) wont upload to dir destination

Tags: php, file

When I submit the form, the image file is not send to his directory. The rest of the data in the which is succesfully inserted. I looked at a couple of tutorials, and I know I dont use the savest way, but I still expect for it to work, could anyone please take a look?

```
 function addData($name, $price, $description, $files)
            {

                            if(!empty($name) || !empty($price) || !empty($description))
                            {
                                   if($sql = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE name= ? LIMIT 1"))
                                    {
                                        $sql->bind_param('s', $name);
                                        $sql->execute();
                                        $sql->store_result();
                                        $sql->fetch();
                                        $numrows = $sql->num_rows;
                                        print_r($numrows);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        echo "something is wrong";
                                    }
                                    if($numrows>0)
                                    {
                                                echo 'duplicate, go to <a href="index.php?res=resources&adm=admin&page=inventory.php">same page</a>';
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        if($insert = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO products (name, price, description) VALUES(?, ?, ?)"))
                                        {

                                                    $insert->bind_param('sds', $name, $price, $description);
                                                    $insert->execute();
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            echo "failed to prepare";
                                        }

                                        //The uploaden image is sent to temp map
                                        if(is_uploaded_file($files['image']['tmp_name']))
                                        {
                                            $valid_types = array(
                                                "image/gif",
                                                "image/png",
                                                "image/jpeg",
                                                "image/pjpeg",
                                            );

                                                if (in_array($files["file"]["type"], $valid_types))
                                                {
                                                    $uploaddir = "./webshop/public/img/content/";
                                                    if(move_uploaded_file($files['image']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir."/".$files['image']['name']));
                                                }

                                                //Shows where its stored
                                                    echo "Stored in: " . 'C:/xampp/htdocs/webshop/public/img/content/' . $files["file"]["name"];


                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                                    echo "didnt inserted the damn thing!";
                                    }

                                }
                                print_r($files);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: what error are you getting? or which of your if tests is failing?

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be missing the `['name']` aspect in the `move_uploaded_file`

```
move_uploaded_file($files['image']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir."/".$files['image']['name']);
```

also notice the `."/".` added between $uploaddir and $files

In your code `$uploaddir/$files['image']`, your goal was to add the trailing slash and then the name of the file, however, you were not using the syntax to concatenate the strings. Therefore you must add the `.` between the variables. You may add the trailing slash in

```
$uploaddir = "./webshop/public/img/content/";
```

so then you could do

```
move_uploaded_file($files['image']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir.$files['image']['name']);
```

**UPDATE**:

You use `If..elseif..` when inserting and handling the file. By your logic, you prepare the statement and if that fails you check the file. It will never do both. You need to remove the elseif and do two seperate checks.

```
if($insert = ..){}
else{echo "failed to prepare";}
if(is_uploaded_file()){}
```

You may wish to check the uploaded file first, move it THEN insert into the database if nothing else goes wrong. Then if the database insert fails, you can unlink (delete) the file since something went wrong.

Comment: Did what you've told me, but the image is still doesnt sent to the content dir, what could it be else? thanks in advance

Comment: Try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', '1');` to the top and see if any errors are displayed. Also, is anything echo'd (does `echo "Stored in:...` display?). Lastly, make sure you have permissions to write to the directory.

Comment: Had them both already in my index page, no errors. I don´t receive echo "Stored in:... display? either

Comment: Thanks, I finally got some errors, Notice: Undefined index: file at the in_array check and one at stored in... unfortunately the file is still not sented to the map. Could you please take a last look?

Comment: it says Stored in: C:/xampp/htdocs/webshop/public/img/content/Array

Comment: you need $files['image'] but you have $files["file"]